# Accessing Vue component object from inside FullCalendar object created inside the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuex

I'm using Full calendar with VueJS and I want to open a custom modal whenever I click a time on the calendar. However, I would need to call a separate function outside of the Full calendar object to open my modal and I'm not sure how to solve that since using `this` inside Full Calendar will refer to that object and the Vue component object. I need someway of getting the Vue component object, here's what I tried so far to no avail

```
export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    methods: {
        myFunc () {
            // should get called from inside fullCalendar below
            this.$store.dispatch()  // this.$store works here since `this` refers to Vue component 
        }
    },
    mounted () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        navLinks: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end) {
            console.log(this)   // refers to Full Calendar object
            console.log(this.$parent)   // getting null, need to call function in vue component
            console.log(this.myFunc()) // cannot do this since this will try to call a function in Full Calendar library
            console.log(this.$parent.$store) // getting null, need to get store that I defined 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common javascript scoping problem newer users get stuck on. `this`, as you’ve discovered, is a fluid concept.

There’s two ways around it. The first is to use an arrow function. Arrow functions keep `this` bound to the context in which they were created:

```
select:  (start, end) => {
        console.log(this)   // should be your vue instance 
    }
```

The other is to store off a reference to `this` at the top of your `mounted` function. This variable is commonly named `self`.

```
var self = this;

....

select: function (start, end) {
        console.log(self) // also your vue instance
    }
```

This way, even if `this` is rebound to a different object inside your callback, you can still get to the original object context through the `self` variable.

This technique is largely obsoleted by arrow functions, but can still be used to support older browsers, and is good to know about.